# Strange error in variable values C++

Tags: c++

I have used this code. Here a string is present from location starting from 4 and length of string is 14. All these calculations are done prior to this code. I am pasting a small snippet of the error containing code.

```
void *data = malloc(4096);
int len = 14;
int fileptr = 4;
string str;
cout<<len<<endl;
cout<<fileptr<<endl;
memcpy(&str, (char *)data+fileptr, len);        
cout<<len<<endl;
cout<<fileptr<<endl;
```

Output i get is:

```
14
4
4012176
2009288233
```

Here i am reading a string "System Catalog" from memory. Its displaying the string correctly. But the values of fileptr and len are abruptly changing after using memcpy() function.

Answer (score 7):

`string` is not the same as a `char*`. `string` is an object. So you can't just `memcpy()` data to it. So the behavior of this code is undefined.

In your case, you are copying 14 bytes of junk data into `str` and corrupting the stack.
The result is that you are overwriting both `len` and `fileptr` with junk from the `malloc()`.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if you want to create a string, you should do it like this:

```
string str = "System Catalog";
```

Comment: I used a char pointer instead of string object. And its workin fine now.

Comment: @Akshay: If you believe this has answered your question you can click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. This applies to your other questions as well.

Answer (score 3):

A string is an object and is not just a sequence of bytes. You cannot just `memcpy` over it from raw memory.

My guess is that in your code the `str` variable is allocated before other variables in stack memory and memcpy-ing over it you are overwriting them.

Note that your phrase "It's displaying the string correctly" has the seed of a common misconception about C++ in it.

When you do bad things in C++ (e.g. writing bytes over an object) you should expect the worst possible behavior. The worst possible behavior however is NOT an ugly result, a crash or a runtime error... but something that **seems** to work but that has bad consequences in the future.

Comment: Agreed - C++ gives you enough rope to seriously hang yourself along with most of the department!

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign *this many* characters from *that* char pointer into a `std::string`, so you should look at what facilities a string object provides for doing that rather than hitting it over the head with `memcpy()`.  As others have noted, `memcpy()` is for use in low-level C-style code, not for interacting with C++ objects.

In particular, you should study the [assignment methods](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign) provided by `std::string`, one of which does exactly what you want -- which isn't a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you actually MUST use memcpy you can get the Internal address of the string to copy to (provided the string is big enough to contain the information you want to copy)

```
    static_cast < char * >(&(str[0]));
```

But this is **VERY VERY BAD**. If you use it, I'm quite sure there are more crazy things going on in your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

`string` is an object - please look up the semantics for it. Why are you doing this and what are you trying to achieve?